# Oracle SQL Regex Non-matching comma

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

We have defined a grammar and are storing expression strings in our database that follow this grammar. One possible term in our expressions is IIF(condition, then, else). I need to query our expressions table for all expressions that contain a '+' in the condition of an IIF.

What I am trying to do with this statement below is search for conditions with any number of non-comma characters followed by a '+' followed by any number of non-comma characters followed by a comma. Where am I going wrong?

`select * from ... and value like '%IIF([^\,]*\+[^\,]*\,%';`

Comment: Are you sure that the `LIKE` operator accepts regular expressions at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using REGEXP_LIKE would work for this type of query. The REGEXP_LIKE function would be called in the where clause and the parameters for the function call would look something like this:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (column_xyz, '.*IFF\([^,]*\+[^,]*,')
```